# How to perform form validation after all fields are validated

Tags: django

I have a form which have a custom form validation logic.

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        ..... my custom validation logic
```

Can i modify it behaviour so that all field validation run first and if all field validations are successful then check for custom validation.

Comment: That is already the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `validators` field attribute for each and every field;

for example:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = EmailField(validators = [email_validator])
```

where `email_validator` is your field validator.

After you modify call the `super` in `clean` function in the form, after that if you write your own clean for a particular field it should work after all the clean actions have been performed.